# Как объединить model и контроллер в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Контроллер:

```
<?php
// Контроллер
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('users',$data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class UsersModel extends Model
{
    public function getIndex() {
        $data = DB::table('pages')->get();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Как мне объединить контроллер с моделью, и передать в view users.blade.php массив $data?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Когда стоит задача в контроллере обратиться к модели, например, при реализации RESTful функционала, то в Laravel 5 это можно сделать при помощи dependency injection.

То есть, если вам artisan создал рыбу контроллера с методом index() без аргументов, можно вписать ей в аргументы и модель, и (если требуется реагировать на параметры запроса) объект Request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Post;

public function index(Request $request, Post $postModel) {

    if ($request->has('latest'))
    {
        // если в запросе есть параметр latest, взять указанное число записей, по умолчанию 10
        // метод getLatestPublishedPosts() определен в модели Post
        $posts = $postModel->getLatestPublishedPosts((int)$request->input('latest', 10));
    }
    else 
    { 
        // если параметра нет, вызвать метод getPublishedPosts(), определенный в модели Post
        $posts = $postModel->getPublishedPosts();        
    }
    // здесь результат отдается в JSON, но если нужна вьюха, то что-то вроде return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts); 
    return json_encode($posts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понял, что значит "объединить контроллер с моделью", но передать в view users.blade.php массив $data можно так.

```
public function index() {
        $model = new UsersModel();
        $data = $model->getIndex();
        return view('users',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

`['data'=>$data]` тут переменная, указанная ключом в массиве, будет переменной в вашем view

Comment: Class 'App\Models\UsersModel' not found

Comment: Вы этот класс подключили? Перед объявлением класса контроллера напишите `use App\Models\UsersModel;`

Comment: Все равно выдает Class 'App\Models\UsersModel' not found

Comment: Попробуйте `use App\UsersModel;`

Comment: Все равно Class 'App\UsersModel' not found

Comment: в какой папке лежит UsersModel.php?

Comment: Да лежит и содержит рабочий код

Comment: <?php
// Модель
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class UsersModel extends Model
{
 public function getIndex() {
  $data = DB::table('pages')->get();
  return $data;
 }
}

Comment: Я не то хотел узнать. У вас модель имеет namespace App а в первый раз ошибка выдавала `Class 'App\Models\UsersModel' not found` Я хотел узнать в какой именно папке лежит файл UsersModel.php

Comment: И еще такой вопрос. Вы модель создавали руками или через php artisan?